# DetailsView DropDownList not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net so I'm just now getting into using TemplateFields.  I have a DetailsView which contains a DropDownList that has it's items populated from my codebehind when the DetailsView is in EditMode.

This much is working fine.  However, after selecting an item from my DropDownList, and clicking "Update" the selection is not updated, however the other DetailsView form values are.

Here is my code:

DetailsView & SQL Queries:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="315px"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound">
    <Fields>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="button" >
            <ControlStyle CssClass="button"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name"
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobID" HeaderText="JobID" SortExpression="JobID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupervisorID" HeaderText="Supervisor"
            SortExpression="SupervisorID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HireDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span class="input-type-text margin-right relative"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>' CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox><img src="images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16"></span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusList"  runat="server">

                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Users] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([ClientID], [UserName], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [JobID], [SupervisorID], [HireDate], [Status]) VALUES (@ClientID, @UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @JobID, @SupervisorID, @HireDate, @Status)"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [ClientID], [UserName], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [JobID], [SupervisorID], [HireDate], [Status] FROM [Users] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Users] SET [ClientID] = @ClientID, [UserName] = @UserName, [Password] = @Password, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [Email] = @Email, [JobID] = @JobID, [SupervisorID] = @SupervisorID, [HireDate] = @HireDate, [Status] = @StatusList WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="curEmp" Type="Int64" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobID" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SupervisorID" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HireDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StatusList" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {

            DropDownList statusList = DetailsView1.FindControl("StatusList") as DropDownList;

            //Add list items (later to be added by database)

            if (statusList != null)
            {
                statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Status", ""));
                statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Active", "Active"));
                statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Inactive", "Inactive"));
                statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Terminated", "Terminated"));
                statusList.DataBind();
            }


            //Highlight selected item in dropdownlist while in edit mode

            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem;
            ListItem liItem = statusList.Items.FindByText(row["Status"].ToString());
            if (liItem != null)
              {
                  statusList.Items.FindByText(row["Status"].ToString()).Selected = true;
              }

        }

    }
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I've tried to change the Update command in my SQLDataSource for the DropDownList (named StatusList) but haven't had any luck.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the statusList is bound to your datasource. You would either need to bind the dropdown in the aspx or in the datasource.

So, like this in the aspx...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="statusList" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("datafield") %>'>
```

or in the data source parameters...

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="status" ControlID="DetailsView1$statusDropDownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this doesn't seem to have resolved the issue.  All other fields still update, except the DropDownList (that I call StatusList). I'm confused because it seems to be in the Update query correctly.  I'm not sure if I have to do something else since it's in an EditTemplate?

Comment: Ah I figured it out.  After binding to the datafield, as you suggested (it's called "Status" in my database) I had to update my Update Parameter and query.  I thought it should pass the DropDownList ID, which was "StatusList".  I changed that to "Status" and it's saving it now.  Thanks for your help